# Is there a way to reset SuperFetch?

Tags: windows-7, superfetch

I recently doubled the amount of RAM in a Windows 7 box and I want to ensure I'm taking full advantage of it. Is there a way to reset SuperFetch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using an SSD, Superfetch is off by default, as it doesn't make sense in an SSD system.

If you're using Server 2008 R2, Superfetch is off by default.

If you're using Windows 7 on a conventional hard drive:

Run `net stop fileinfo`, and delete the following 3 files:

- `AgGlFaultHistory.db`
- `AgGlFgAppHistory.db`
- `AgGlGlobalHistory.db`

(all under `C:\Windows\Prefetch`)

`SC Start SysMain` will get it going again.

Comment: fwiw - Anyone using Rammap and experiencing [c0000417 - An invalid parameter was passed to a C runtime function.](http://forum.sysinternals.com/rammapexe-crash_topic23026.html) on a 64-bit system, resetting Superfetch was what solved that issue.